# How to import HTML into HTML while build?

Tags: webpack, parceljs

I have a project with the following structure:

```
my-site
├── home.html
├── about.html
└── shared
    ├── header.html
    └── footer.html
```

my-site\home.html:

```html
<html>
    <!-- Insert contents of .\shared\header.html here -->
    <span>home</span>
    <!-- Insert contents of .\shared\footer.html here -->
</html>
```

my-site\about.html:

```html
<html>
    <!-- Insert contents of .\shared\header.html here -->
    <span>about</span>
    <!-- Insert contents of .\shared\footer.html here -->
</html>
```

my-site\shared\header.html:

```html
<div>header</div>
```

my-site\shared\footer.html:

```html
<div>footer</div>
```

I need a build operation that creates a `dist` directory with the following structure:

```
dist
├── home.html
├── about.html
└── shared
    ├── header.html
    └── footer.html
```

dist\home.html:

```html
<html>
<div>header</div>
    <span>home</span>
<div>footer</div>
</html>
```

dist\about.html:

```html
<html>
<div>header</div>
    <span>about</span>
<div>footer</div>
</html>
```

The content of dist\shared\header.html and dist\shared\footer.html may be the same as their my-app counterparts.

My intent is similar to [this Medium post](https://medium.com/hackernoon/using-html-components-with-webpack-f383797a5ca), however, it uses client side JavaScript (`document.onload`) to fetch the shared HTML. I want to generate static HTML files that are fetched in a single GET.

Are there any known approaches to achieve this using any bundler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [handlebars-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-webpack-plugin#usage) to inject [handlebars partials](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html) into your handlebars templates. Example usage can be found [here](https://github.com/LordKa0S/qBittorrent-website/blob/d8cc011c581987b0444a70179f58bf69c9781920/webpack.hbs.js).